# Claymore Mining (CANNOT ALLOCATE MEMORY)

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining

I recently started using Claymore Miner CPU.

I've set up everything and it runs fine, it just runs in slow mode.

At the beginning of mining it says: "CANNNOT ALLOCATE MEMORY! Error #103-1-1"
I use Windows 10 and have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz processor.

Would love the help so I can mine faster!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you have not enabled huge pages on Windows 10. You can follow the directions on my website: https://www.cryptocurrencyfreak.com/2017/08/29/monero-mining-xmr-stak-cpu-windows-10/ at the end of the article to enable huge pages.

I also recommend giving xmr-stak-cpu a try. I have always had better luck with it than Claymore.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please note that you *must* disclose your affiliation with this website, see [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: It sure feels weird to be questioned as a scammer if you only have good intentions; but from everyone else's point of view, if there is an undisclosed potential conflict of interest, it looks as though you're trying to present a potentially biased opinion as unbiased.  Again, even if you are correct and being honest being helpful, disclosure of affiliations is required.